# Capture network traffic in Selenium in 2022

Tags: selenium, automation, browsermob, webdriver-w3c-spec

What is the best way in 2022 to capture network logs in selenium? I am aware there are multiple examples that use `browsermob` as a proxy server. But looking at GitHub looks like browsermob repo is not being maintained anymore.